# Redirecting vcftools file in linux - tips

Tags: linux, bioinformatics, genetics, vcf-variant-call-format, vcftools

Here is the code that gets the VCF file from a specific region using `tabix` and then filters it for specific (european) population using 'keep' option from vcftools.

```
####select specific population
if [ "$POP_FILE" != "" ]; then
    vcftools --vcf temp.vcf --keep $POP_FILE --recode --recode-INFO-all > temp2.vcf 2> /dev/null
else
    cp -f temp.vcf temp2.vcf    
fi
```

**PROBLEM**: it creates the recode.vcf file but then the redirection is not happening as the temp2 file is empty

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid vcftools and use bcftools (https://github.com/samtools/bcftools) instead:

```
if [ "$POP_FILE" != "" ]; then
  bcftools view temp.vcf -S $POP_FILE -o temp2.vcf
else
  cp -f temp.vcf temp2.vcf
fi
```

To install bcftools:

```
git clone --branch=develop git://github.com/samtools/bcftools.git
git clone --branch=develop git://github.com/samtools/htslib.git
cd htslib && make && cd ..
cd bcftools && make && cd ..
sudo cp bcftools/bcftools /usr/local/bin/
```